# What's the difference between "Pixel" and "RGB" in GIMP's Pointer Information dialog?

Tags: color, gimp

The following dialog (in GIMP 2.10) shows two different R, G, B values for "Pixel" and "RGB" settings:

[image: GIMP Pointer Dialog]

Why are they different?

I assume that "Pixel" means the pixel value as stored in the image *(in this case, Display P3)*, and "RGB" is one of the standard color spaces such as sRGB, is that correct? Is that documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick experiment show that RGB(%) is

1. independent of the image mode (linear or gamma-corrected)
2. identical to pixel in a gamma-corrected image

So the Pixel is the internal data representation, and RGB(%) if the equivalent RGB triplet for your usual color representation. An experiment you can do is:

- make two copies of the same image, one gamma-corrected, the other one linear
- set the foreground color to some RGB value

Paint both images:

- they will visually have the same color
- the RGB value of what you painted will be identical on both images
- it will also be the RGB values you set in the Foreground color selector
- the Pixel values will be different
- in the linear image, you will find that *RGB<sup>gamma</sup>=Pixel* (where *gamma* is around 2.2)